# MapThread over large graph

Tags: list-manipulation, performance-tuning

I am trying to build a very large graph with approximately $16\,000\,000$ edges, each being a two-dimensional integer vector. I have a list of edges in the form $\{\{e_{11}, e_{12}\}, \{e_{21}, e_{22}\}, \dotsc\}$, where $e_{11} = \{n, m\}$, etc. To convert it into a usable edge-list I need to turn every element of this list into a rule:

```
edgeList = MapThread[Rule, Transpose[edgelist]];
```

This works fast enough when there are $3\,000\,000$ edges but is too slow for $16\,000\,000$. What is the best way to speed up the threading?

Comment: Please clarify: is `edgelist` of the form `{{{6, 6}, {7, 0}, {9, 1}, {7, 8}, {3, 6}}` or `{{{6, 9}, {2, 1}}, {{7, 2}, {9, 5}}, {{8, 3}, {1, 1}}, {{4, 0}, {0, 1}}, {{9, 9}, {3, 6}}}`?

Comment: Is it 16/3 times as slow or much much worse than that?

Comment: @Mr.Wizard The latter.

Comment: @Ymareth much much worse (I didn't even try to wait for the end).

Comment: I updated my answer.  I think it is possible that memory consumption is an issue.  Please try the in-place method and see if it works.

Answer (score 7):

With the correct data dimensions I don't believe my original recommendation of `Inner` is (easily) applicable.  Further, Oleksandr revealed that it is not the fastest even in that case in later versions.  Instead I'll just offer a few options and an observation:

```
list = RandomInteger[999, {2*^6, 2, 2}];

MapThread[Rule, Transpose[list]]              // ByteCount
Rule @@@ list                                 // ByteCount
Thread[Rule @@ Transpose[list]]               // ByteCount
(list2 = list; list2[[All, 0]] = Rule; list2) // ByteCount
```

> ```
> 640000032
>
> 640000032
>
> 640000032
>
> 432000032
> ```

It can be seen that on my system the last method uses about a third less memory than the others.  I don't yet know why.  More memory can be conserved by this method, comparatively, if the original list may be modified in place:

```
list = RandomInteger[999, {2*^6, 2, 2}];  (* in a fresh Kernel *)
list = MapThread[Rule, Transpose[list]];
MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> ```
> 1022926416
> ```

```
list = RandomInteger[999, {2*^6, 2, 2}];
list[[All, 0]] = Rule;
MaxMemoryUsed[]
```

> ```
> 350925448
> ```

We get by using about one third of the memory used by the original method.
If your code is failing because of memory consumption this may solve the problem.

Comment: @Oleksandr I had to rewrite the answer since I used the wrong data the first time.  Would you mind running timings for the present operations?

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't notice that either. Here they are again. Version 9: all methods use 870MB of memory except the last which uses 290MB (using undocumented new in 9 `MaxMemoryUsed[code_]`); `ByteCount`s are 608M and 480M and normalized timings are `{1.000000, 0.957547, 0.976415, 0.806604}` in the order that you show them. In version 8 the `ByteCount`s are 823M (first three) and 544M (last) and the timings are `{1.000000, 0.995714, 0.959714, 0.656286}`.

Comment: I also noticed that simply transposing a list this large is very slow.

Comment: @level1807 How does my recommendation (`list[[All, 0]] = Rule;`) work for you?

Comment: Not better... I guess I will have to implement a different algorithm for the whole problem and avoid such large graphs.

Comment: @level1807 I'm sorry I couldn't help.  Perhaps if you post a summary of the problem someone with experience can help you craft an approach.

Comment: Actually the problem is about Sequence Alignment. It really would be great to find out how the native Mathematica command `SequenceAlignment` works. It gave the right answer for two 4000-symbol-long strings in a second.